# Business model of taking a percentage

Tags: vocabulaire, commerce, économie

I want to find one word to express the business model here. For example, in some online dressing store (eg, videdressing.com), the provider of the site takes eg, 5% of the price from the seller when a product is sold. Is there a french word to say this business model of taking a percentage from sellers?

Comment: I don't know if the "brick-and mortar" term ["**vente en/par consignation**"](https://www.lucbrialy.com/vente-en-consignation.html) is used in/would be applicable to online boutiques (nothing is physically consigned, so probably not), but it does involve (according to the link @ par.9) "[the consignee(/site provider?) receiving] *un pourcentage, une somme fixe ou une marge*," & if the site provider has an exclusive right to insist that the product be sold only on his/her site, maybe some kind of "virtual consignment" could somehow be argued, making the notion perhaps relevant to your scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The percentage would be called *une commission*.

About the business model, I guess we would say that the provider *est rémunéré à la commission*.

You could also say that the provider *se rémunère via un pourcentage sur les ventes*. Or *par une commission sur les ventes*.